# NP-complete variants of NPI problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

Motivated by these posts, [An NP-complete variant of factoring](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4769/495) and [Relationship between symmetry and computational intractability](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/871/495), It seems to be worthwhile to investigate the different factors that increase the hardness of problems in $NPI$ from an intermediate complexity to full $NP$-completeness. I'm interested in other $NP$-complete variants of $NPI$ problems. Ideally, a recent survey paper of $NP$-complete variants of $NPI$ problems would be the best answer?

**EDIT July 1st, 2012** The bounty will be awarded to the person that lists the maximum number of such problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Papadimitriou's paper "[On total functions, existence, theorems and computational complexity](http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/papadimX.pdf)":

*Nondeterministic multivalued functions with values that 
are polynomially verifiable and guranteed to exist form an
interesting class (called $TFNP$) between P and NP ...*

*.... It is quite interesting, in view of Theorem 2.1,
that in some cases of problems in $TFNP$, if together with the input
we are also given one of the solutions
that are guaranteed to exist, then the problem indeed becomes NP-complete ...*

For example the TRICHROMATIC TRIANGLE problem is in $TFNP$, but the SECOND TRICHROMATIC TRIANGLE is $NPC$ (the paper contains a sketch of the proof).

Comment: TRICHROMATIC TRIANGLE was later shown to be PPAD-complete, which is a well-known class by now, while imo similar to SECOND TRICHROMATIC TRIANGLE one can make an NPC variant of basically any TFNP problem, so this kind of examples I would call cheating.

Answer (score 1):

The [graph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) is in NP but not known to be in P or NP-complete.

A generalization, the [subgraph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem), is NP-complete since asking if some subgraph of the input graph with $n$ vertices is isomorphic to a cycle of length $n$ is the [Hamiltonian cycle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_cycle).

Comment: Thanks Tyson. I'm aware of these trivial examples. I'm only interested in non-trivial cases.

Comment: What does it mean to be a trivial example?

Comment: I suspect "trivial" is being used as a synonym for "known to the OP"

Comment: @Tyson, in addition to Suresh's comment, "non-Trivial" means "interesting" examples to the experts in TCS. For instance, I would consider the examples which I cited in my question as "interesting". I hope this would help.